# downsampling: get constant value. E.g. sensor name from GROUP BY

Tags: influxdb

I created a continuous query to downsample readings from temperature sensors in my influxdb to store hourly means for a longer time. There are readings of multiple sensors in one table. Upon executing the query, the sensors ip is missing.

Basic data looks like this:

```
> SELECT ip,tC  FROM ht LIMIT 5
name: ht
time                ip           tC
----                --           --
1671057540000000000 192.168.0.83 21
1671057570000000000 192.168.0.83 21
1671057750000000000 192.168.0.17 21.38
```

The continuous query (simplified without CREATE ... END):

```
SELECT last(ip), mean("tC") AS "mean_temp" INTO "downsampled"."ht_downsampled"  FROM "ht"  GROUP BY time(1h),ip
```

The issue is, the value of 'ip' is only a tag, not the value in the table and subsequently is missing in the table the query inserts into:

```
name: ht
tags: ip=192.168.0.17
time                ip mean_temp          mean_hum
----                -- ---------          --------
1671055200000000000    21.47              42.75
1671058800000000000    21.39428571428571  48.785714285714285
1671062400000000000    21.314999999999998 51.625
```

Why is last(ip) not producing any value?
Can I get the value from the 'tags' into the table?
Is there a different approach to group data with a constant value?

Answer (score 2):

Could you just try query the **ip** instead of the **last(ip)** since you are grouping by the ip in the statement already?

Sample code:

```
SELECT ip, mean("tC") AS "mean_temp" INTO "downsampled"."ht_downsampled"  FROM "ht"  GROUP BY time(1h), ip
```

Comment: No, influx expects an aggregate function for all entites when using group by